# Conditional expectation of a martingale

Tags: statistics, stochastic-processes, conditional-expectation, martingales

Let $X_n$ be a real-valued martingale.
Can one proof this:
$\mathbb{E}((X_{n+m-1}-X_{n})(X_{n+m}-X_{n+m-1})^2|\mathcal{F}_n) \neq 0$
and $\mathbb{E}((X_{n+m-1}-X_{n})^2(X_{n+m}-X_{n+m-1})|\mathcal{F}_n) = 0$?

*I am trying to understand the proof of proposition 1 on page 45 of [this paper](https://ssrn.com/abstract=3173581).*

Comment: Martingale property alone won't give the values of these integrals.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy true, thank you! Changed the question!

Comment: You need more conditions. As a counterexample to the first inequality, let $X_n \equiv 0$ be the constant Martingale. Then that expectation is clearly 0.

Answer (score 3):

The second part is true (provided that all the expectations are well defined). 
Let $U:= (X_{n+m-1}-X_n)^2$ and $V=X_{n+m}-X_{n+m-1}$. Then by the tower property of the condition expectation, 
$$
\mathbb E\left[UV\mid \mathcal F_n\right]=\mathbb E\left[\mathbb E\left[ UV\mid\mathcal F_{n+m-1}\right]\mid \mathcal F_n\right],
$$
Since $U$ is $\mathcal F_{n+m-1}$-measurable, it follows that 
$$
\mathbb E\left[ UV\mid\mathcal F_{n+m-1}\right]= U\mathbb E\left[ V\mid\mathcal F_{n+m-1}\right]
$$
and by the martingale property, the last conditional expectation is $0$.